# Xamarin stuck at “Found device: emulator-5554”

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

## Xamarin stuck at “Found device: emulator-5554”

I am currently learning Xamarin for Android app development. I installed the xamarin workload for visual studio a few days ago. Today I built a hello world app with Xamarin, tried to run it with an emulator. When I ran the app, everthing went fine until the device loaded succesfully, when the putput window in visual studio said `Found device: emulator-5554`.

At that point visual studio and the emulator ‘stopped’, not hanged, stopped. The status bar said `Ready` and the build animation that appears when building a project showed that the process was half completed. I waited for several minutes, but nothing changed. I tried to ‘preload’ the emulator like adviced on other stackoverflow questions, which again didn’t work.

**UPDATE**: Now Visual Studio is stuck at `Waiting for emulator to be ready...` which takes forever and never loads.

I work on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 Community with the Xamarin workload, along with the default `Galaxy Nexus API 23` Android Emulator.

Thank You! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try to repair Visual Studio. For usage, please refer to：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022.

Comment: Damn, still no solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in Visual Studio when you use Android Emulator.
You can try 2 ways for resolve this problem.

First way

- 1: Go in "Tools", then Android then Android Device Manager.
- 2: Run simulator
- 3: Then Start your project

Second way

- 1: Go in "Tools", then Android then Android Device Manager.
- 2: Delete all yours Android Simulators
- 3: Create a new Simulator
- 4: Run simulator
- 5: Then start your project

Let me know if works :)

Comment: Did not work :(

Comment: Ok, try to change the emulator whit another that have a most recent API like Api30

Comment: Again doesn't work. Checked installed sdks in Android Sdk Manager, but Api 28 is installed. Tried to use Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 which doesn't work as I said.

Comment: Tried to use Android 10.0, updated all the settings like target version and minimum version, still doesn’t work.

Comment: Have you try to re-install visual studio?

Comment: Maybe I'll just use my physical device, as I am not a professional dev, and don't do 'serious' coding.